# Do I need to compare the revision of events since etcd does not gaurantee linearizability of watch response?

Tags: watch, etcd

As the [document](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/learning/api_guarantees/) says, it does not ensure linearizability for watch operations.

> etcd does not ensure linearizability for watch operations. Users are expected to verify the revision of watch responses to ensure correct ordering.

Does it mean that if a have a single watcher, i need to check the revision of each Events in the WatchResponse? Say if I receive 5 events in 1 WatchResponse, is it possible that the revision of the 5 event appear out of order?

Or

Does it mean that if there are multipe watch operations, it does not gaurantee the linearizability for multiple watch operations?